# Sliding Window Detection

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

Suppose that we have a labeled training set of $n$ closely cropped images of cars $(x_1, y_1) , \dots, (x_n, y_n)$. We then train a CNN on this. Let's say we have $m$ test images. Then for each of the $m$ images, do we use the trained CNN on a cropped out portion of the box to detect whether there is a car or not? If the object is large, wouldn't having a large sliding window have better performance than a smaller sliding window?

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community! I think it would be useful if you can explain more in detail the relationship between the sliding window and the test dataset: why do you need a sliding window in the first place? Are you referring to a specific model that uses a sliding window? If yes, edit your question to add these details. What is the context of your question, model and problem?

Comment: @nbro: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/23/sliding-windows-for-object-detection-with-python-and-opencv/   The idea is to use the "non-convolutional" version of YOLO.